# Examples of Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Can someone give examples for these types of sequences?

1. A sequence that is monotone but not convergent
2. A sequence that is not bounded but is convergent
3. A sequence that is monotone but not Cauchy
4. A sequence that is monotone and bounded, but not Cauchy

For 1. I think one exists, but for 2. and 4., not one exists; for 3. I think one might exists as well

I am only dealing with $\mathbb{R}^2$ here though

Comment: How do you define monotone in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: increasing/decreasing

Comment: I think you should check the definition of monotone.

1. $a_n  = n$ is monotone and not convergent.
2. A sequence that is not bounded does not converge.
3. it is given by an example in no 1.
4. you should check monotone convergence theorem and definition of Cauchy sequence, it does not exist.

Comment: @Jack: there is no total order on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer here for sequences in $\Bbb{R}$ (or subsets thereof), since it is ordered and hence monotonicity makes sense.

1) Consider the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$

2) This doesn't exist. Only a finite number are a distance greater than $\epsilon$ from the point it converges to. A finite number of finite real numbers have a maximum, which serves as a bound.

3) The example from 1) works here as well.

4) All monotone bounded sequences are Cauchy. To see this let $x_n$ be a sequence assume that for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every $N > 0$ there exists $n,m > N$ such that $|x_n - x_m| > \epsilon$. You can then construct a subsequence $x_{n_i}$ containing pairs $x_{n_i}, x_{n_{i+1}}$ which each are a distance greater than a fixed $\epsilon$ from one another, which contradicts boundedness.

Answer (score 0):

1) The sequence is necessarily unbounded. For example the sequence $(n)$

2) Every convergent sequence is bounded.

3) Find an unbounded sequence in $\mathbb R$. For example the sequence $(n)$.

4)The space must be incomplete.

Comment: for the ones that exist, can I get examples? this is not for homework

Comment: sequence n as in the natural numbers?

Comment: yes, as a subset of R.